# Serialization: Cannot convert type string[][] to string[]

Tags: c#, arrays, xmlserializer

I have a class with a jagged array. When I try to serialize it, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=Unable
>   to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0030: Cannot convert
>   type 'string[][]' to 'string[]' error CS0029: Cannot implicitly
>   convert type 'string[]' to 'string[][]'

A simple program to reproduce the problem:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace JaggedArraySerialization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1));
            var class1 = new Class1();
            using (TextWriter stream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\test.xml"))
            { 
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, class1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And class Class1

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace JaggedArraySerialization
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Class1
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string[][] MyJaggedArray { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I serialize my jagged array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the type on the property `MyJaggedArray`, like this:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Class1
    {
        [XmlElement(Type = typeof(string[][]))]
        public string[][] MyJaggedArray { get; set; }
    }
```